# How to get top 3 from each "by group" in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I have a table that looks something like:

Favourite color | Favourite Food | Favourite Dance | Date

Now I want to group by favourite color and favourite food. Then take top 3 in each group ordered by date (the latest). I just cannot seem to get it to work using LINQ.

Comment: some sample code of your classes would be good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
from x in thingy
group x by new { x.Color, x.Food } into g
select new {
    g.Key.Color, 
    g.Key.Food, 
    Items = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(3) 
}
```